# Memorizing Religious Texts

Tags: mantras, vishnu-sahasranama, lalita-sahasranama, gurukul

Namaskara 
How can one effectively memorize extensive texts like Vishnu Shasranama, Lalitha Shasranama, Soundarya Lahari etc for long-term retention?
Additionally, what **memorization techniques** are employed in Gurukul learning to master vast collections of religious texts?